# Javascript minesweeper game, can't increment the right cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a simple minesweeper game in Javascript. I have a 2-dimensional array (called "mineInput") to hold the locations of all the mines. And I have a separate array "result" which records the number of mines adjacent to each cell.

I have 2 nested for loops to iterate over each row and each column in "result" and check every sell in 'mineInput". If there is a mine, I increment the mine count with `result[i][j]++;`. However I noticed weird behavior where the entire column is incremented instead of just one cell.

this:

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

followed by: `result[i][j]++;`

becomes:

```
[ [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ] ]
```

instead of:

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Here is the full code (pls excuse the obscene number of console logs).
https://repl.it/BIYH/2

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I've corrected your post from calling this game "Minecraft" to calling it "Minesweeper". Minecraft is the 3D explore-and-build-stuff game; Minesweeper is the 2D find-the-hidden-mines game that I'm pretty sure you're trying to ask about here.

Comment: Have you tried (result [i][j])++;  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the following code:

```
var result = [];
var newRow = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  newRow.push(0);
}
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  result.push(newRow);
}
```

You add the same array over and over again to the array `result`. Instead, you want to create a new array for each row:

```
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var newRow = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
      newRow.push(0);
    }
    result.push(newRow);
}
```

An array is an object in javascript, and objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: I knew it was something silly. I feel dumb now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issue is early in your code where you initialise your arrays

```
var result = [];
var newRow = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  newRow.push(0);
}
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  result.push(newRow);
}
```

You have created only one `newRow` array and added it to your `result` array 3 times. So you could show this like:

```
newRow == [0,0,0]
result == [newRow, newRow, newRow]
```

When you increment you add to one cell in the `newRow` array which gives

```
newRow == [0,1,0]
result == [newRow, newRow, newRow] therefore
result = [[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0]]
```

you can fix this like this:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  // create a new array for each row
  var newRow = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    newRow.push(0);
  }

  result.push(newRow);
}
```